# Excel VBA - how to handle many cell references without creating a mess

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose you have an Excel workbook and you need to write a macro that takes inputs from many different cell references, and updates values at many different cell references, how do you keep the code neat and maintainable?

It would be helpful to know:

- best practices
- useful tricks
- unavoidable difficulties
- necessary trade offs

If there are links to existing guides or discussions that would be helpful too. I haven't been able to find any.

Edit: I found http://www.eusprig.org/best-practice.htm very useful - from the European Spreadsheet Risk Interest Group (EuSPRIG).

Comment: i think this would be more appropriate here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: **[This link](http://spreadsheetsuperstar.com/vba-code-good-bad-ugly/)** may be helpful at a basic level. Things I do: declare all my varibles; use named ranges and meaningful variable names; reorganize sheets to group like things together (inputs, constants, output, etc.); do reads from and writes to sheet in separate code blocks; only turn to VBA for things that cannot be accomplished in well-organized worksheet(s).

Comment: Not really a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: ALWAYS use `Option Explicit`, organize codes into modules, use sensible naming conventions for your variables. Use named ranges whenever possible. Comment your code liberally. Create test cases to make sure you didn't introduce bugs ("with these known inputs I should get these known outputs"); do regression testing. Put your code under revision control. Good luck.

Comment: Just an idea, what about creating two classes, one e.g. InputManager and second e.g. OutputManager. Input manager will wrap the access to input ranges and output manager work with output ranges. So you keep the input and output ranges on one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It slightly depends om what the macro is going to do, but I use 'calculation' sheets, where I gather together the data I need for the macro, and output the results there.

I tend to do this do in defined ranges.

The result data can then be referenced from elsewhere.

Tricks: One thing I do is to create a visual 'check off' for each piece of input data as it's used. This just enables me to make sure that all the data I thought I was going to use, I have used.

Comment: Thanks. This is the approach I'm going for. Something similar to a model-view-controler approach.

Answer (score 0):

Following Naming criteria is better solution , irrespictve of language.

- in_name_range, out_name_range
- in_num_range, out_num_range

  - Check points and adding watch , would surely help.
  - If you are going for modularity, Take care about updated ranges
    (As you can't return more than one value at a time better write ranges in some predefined order in some sheet. This works for me.)